# Remove comma from jQuery array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, forms

**Problem:**

I have an array in JS that looks like this:

```
["intelligence", "skin", "weight", "volume"]
```

This is stored in a var called "newListASource". I apply this var to a form and then submit it using POST.

```
// Form destination
var formUrl     = 'explorer.php',

// Generate the form
$form = $("<form action='"+ formUrl +"' method='post'></form>")
        .append("<input type='hidden' name='Perspective' value='" + newListASource + "'>")
        .append("<input type='hidden' name='form_submitted' value='true'>")
        .appendTo('body');

// Submit the form
$form.submit();
```

When I pick it up through PHP and print it out, it gives me a string with commas. For instance:

```
skin,weight,intelligence,volume
```

**Desired output I would like is (with trimmed spaces in the beginning and end):**

```
skin weight intelligence volume
```

Comment: A side question: What did you mean with "pick it up through php"?

Comment: @reporter The form is submitted using POST to a PHP page. On that PHP page I echo the POST variable Perspective and I get the values in the form of: skin,weight,intelligence,volume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using an array use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with the separator as `' '`

```
"<input type='hidden' name='Perspective' value='" + newListASource.join(' ') + "'>"
```

Answer (score 5):

`newListASource.join(' ')` will give you the desired result -

```
// Generate the form
$form = $("<form action='"+ formUrl +"' method='post'></form>")
    .append("<input type='hidden' name='Perspective' value='" 
        + newListASource.join(' ') + "'>")
    .append("<input type='hidden' name='form_submitted' value='true'>")
    .appendTo('body');

// Submit the form
$form.submit();
```

See the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Currently you are getting comma separated values because `newListASource.toString()` is called whenever you are concatenating your array with a string, and this is the default behavior of `toString` method for arrays. When you call `join`, however, it converts your array to a string, separated by the delimiter that you pass to it as argument. So you get values separated by spaces in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
newListASource.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.join()` and `$.trim()`:

```
// Form destination
var formUrl     = 'explorer.php',
    newListASource = newListASource.join(' ');
```

then in the form you can change to this:

```
$.trim(newListASource)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = ["intelligence", "skin", "weight", "volume"];


 var result = ary.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like that:

```
arr.join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is just send the array as an array!

```
var formUrl     = 'explorer.php';
var $form = $("<form action='"+ formUrl +"' method='post'></form>")
    .append("<input type='hidden' name='form_submitted' value='true'>")
    .appendTo('body');
while(newListASource.length)
    $form.append($("<input type='hidden' name='Perspective[]' value=''>").val(newListASource.shift()));
$form.submit();
```

Php will then actually have an array inside `$_POST['Perspective']`.
(Beware the input name is now Perspective**[ ]** to indicate it will be an array.)